# In Kusto, how can I run a user defined function that contains toscalar() for each row in my table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a query similar to below:

```
let some_function = (param1: string, param2: long) {
    let some_data = get_some_data(param1);
    let x = toscalar(some_data | summarize sum(some_column));
    param2 > x;
};
let final_table = some_function(); // final_table has columns Param1 and Param2 
final_table
| extend isBigger = some_function(Param1, Param2)
```

`some_data` looks like below:

| Date | Count (some_column) | .. | .. | .. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03.04.2023 | 5 |  |  |  |
| 02.04.2023 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 01.04.2023 | 4 |  |  |  |

I'm basically using this table and summing up the values in `some_column`. Then using `toscalar` to turn the result into `long` and assigning it to `x`.

But I'm receiving the below error:

```
Relop semantic error: CRT0018: 'toscalar': can't use 'Param1' as it is defined outside its row-context scope. (see: https://aka.ms/toscalar_limitations).
```

From my understanding, I'm receiving this error because I'm calling `toscalar()` function for each row in the `final_table`.

I would like to calculate what `some_function` does for each row, but I couldn't find a way to do it without using `toscalar`.

I would appreciate any suggestion! Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please provide some sample data for what you are trying to achieve? Like what `get_some_data()` is doing and what is  value for `some_column`?

Comment: By sample data I meant input and output data.

Comment: `get_some_data()` just queries some table in my DB, and `some_column` is an integer. Sample data is added to the post

Comment: Below are my observations from posted code.
1. `some_function()` will throw error while calling as need to use `print()` 
 to return scalar value.
2. As mentioned, *final_table* is having *columns Param1 and Param 2*. As per code the table is getting populated using `some_function()` and the function return scalar value as `summarize` and `toscalar()` is being used.